# Proper response to Telegram.org "Error 500: RPC_SEND_FAIL"

Tags: python, api, telegram

After sending an auth.sendCode method to the telegram.org server I am receiving the following in return:

```
{'MessageContainer': [{'msg': {u'bad_msg_notification': {u'bad_msg_seqno': 4, u'bad_msg_id': 6334696945916753920L, u'error_code': 35}}, 'seqno': 4, 'msg_id': 6334696948768376833L}, {'msg': {u'msgs_ack': {u'msg_ids': [6334696945916753920L]}}, 'seqno': 4, 'msg_id': 6334696948768387073L}]})
```

then:

```
('sentCode: ', {u'req_msg_id': 6334696967778138112L, u'result': {u'error_message': '[1474911573] [6609] Error 500: RPC_SEND_FAIL: 27029.\nUnhandled Exception caught in file lib/global.lib.php at line 4622.\nBacktrace:\n#0 : 0x16497a7\n#1 : 0xc06579\n#2 : 0x14ddb18\n#3 : 0xc90029\n#4 : 0x127c5e7\n#5 : 0x12b634d\n#6 : 0x13a56d1\n#7 : 0x13a4e27\n#8 : 0x5a5946\n#9 : 0x16052d2\n#10 : 0x7fdd67383d10\n#11 : 0x7fff6e7b2790\n', u'error_code': -504}})
```

I understand the `bad_msg_seqno`, I think, and have a separate question submitted for proper resolution. But the `RPC_SEND_FAIL` appears to be an error on the server side and, according to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors), should be communicated to the telegram developers. What is the best way to do that?

BTW: this error wasn't happening a week ago with the same code. I came back from vacation, ran the unchanged code, and boom!

Answer (score 1):

The telegram.org servers are now responding as expected, no more `Error 500` conditions. All I did was wait a few hours, and updated from layer 54 to layer 55. I didn't see anything in the new layer that would cause the problem so I have to assume something was fixed on the server side. Time will tell.